# HTML code in Python Flask cannot load image, but when opened locally image loads

Tags: html, flask, localhost

I am currently learning Python Flask therefore would be using Python code to run a HTML code. I have a folder called "Codes", inside the "Codes" folder there are 2 other folders called "Images" and "Templates", 1 python file called "basic.html". Inside of "Images", there is 1 image that is called "Logo.jpg" and inside of "Templates", I have an HTML file called "basic.html".

Structure:

```
Codes
  |-- basic.py
  |-- Images
      |-- Logo.jpg
  |-- Templates
      |-- basic.html
```

Inside the HTML file, I am using the `<img>` tag, and this is my code:

`<img src = "C:\Users\Lamont\Desktop\Codes\Images\Logo.jpg" alt = "Logo">`

Why is it that when I run the Python code that links to the HTML file in localhost, the image does not load but when I double click on the basic.html file inside of "Template" folder, the page actually loads the image?

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you all in advance!

Initially I thought there was something wrong with my file path. If I changed the file path to an image address from the internet, my localhost would load that image, so I changed my file path from absolute to relative and also tried to start with "https://localhost" or just "localhost", but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a 'static' folder and use `url_for` in Jinja2 to load your pictures in a template. So:

1. Put your pictures in `/static/images/` (this works out of the box; no need to declare /static/ since it is the default (see: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/static/)
2. Change the code to load the image to: `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo.jpg') }}" alt="Logo">`
3. I would suggest only use lower-case (e.g., logo.jpg) since Windows and Unix handle file names with capitals differently and might cause some debug issues in the future if you deploy your app
4. Add `from flask import url_for` to the file that contains the view/route of the template

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thank you so much, it worked!!!